# How to use printf to separate multiple decimal numbers and round all those numbers to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, printf

I want to use `printf` to organize my results of a code. The result of my code will have four decimal numbers. All those numbers has to be rounded to **2 decimal** places and are organized on the same line.

I do not know much about how to use `printf`, I just know that `%.2f` can round my answer to **2 decimal** places, and I do not know how to do the rest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class CirclePoints
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the radius of your circle: ");
        double radius = in.nextDouble();

        double x = 1.0;
        double z = x;
        double absY;
        double y1D;
        double y2D;
        double y1;
        double y2;

        System.out.println("Point on a circle with radius: " + radius);

        //System.out.printf(); want to get something like (x   y1   x   y2) as the reult that can match the bottom
        while(x >= -(z))
        {
            y1D = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2)));
            y2D = -(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2))));
            System.out.printf ("%.2f",x, y1D, y2D );
            x = x-0.1;
        }
    } 
}
```

The actual out put should be something like

x     y1     x     y2

1.00   0.00   1.00  0.00

0.90   0.44   0.90  -0.44

...

-0.90  0.44   0.90  -0.44

-1.00  0.00   -1.00  0.00

Comment: This result should appear when the user input is equals to 1. Sorry for not saying that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 different to build print methods in java. By default, `Java.lang` package has been imported to all java classes so System class is in it. Three of the print methods are preceded by `System.out.`. Those are `System.out.print`, `System.out.println`, `System.out.printf`. There is no difference between `print` and `println` apart from the fact that `println`(print line) goes to a new line after the execution. The `printf` is referred to as the print format which means we can use the `%` character to indicate special cases. Like `%n` indicates and `%t` new tab. `%.2f` mean float with two decimal points and it will be rounded to the nearest value.

As I mentioned above the fourth print method is used to represent error outcomes. The syntax should be `System.err` instead of `System.out`. There is no difference with normal `out.print` methods and these `err.print` methods but the output is in red.

For your code change,

`System.out.printf ("%.2f",x, y1D, y2D );` to

`System.out.printf ("%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %n",x, y1D, x, y2D );`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but when I had tried what you said to change in my code, it had only showed the first x when I run it. Also I forgot to put another x, it should be between y1D and y2D.

Comment: What is the purpose of using a 'while' loop? To run 10 times the Code?

Comment: I want it to run as long as it is between the range of x and -x. For example if x equals to 1, than it should give the out put of 1.00, 0.90, 0.80 ... -0.80, -0.90, -1.00

Comment: Try this System.out.printf ("%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %n",x, y1D, x, y2D );